# filling a Django form from a separate requests.post python script

Tags: python, django

while reading about the Requests library, it occurred to me that I could try to fill a form by using it. So, since I have Django and the server, I first checked that I got the URL well and got a 200 answer code.

like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('127.0.0.1/myform')
print(r.status_code)
```

and yes, it was a 200

so the next step was going to be entering a value in the textfield, actually the form, for this example is just one field.

I tried this:

```
r = requests.post('127.0.0.1/myform', data ={'name' : 'Mexico'})
```

and nothing was entered. Here I have like 3 intriguing questions:

1. When I inspect the element, because the form was created using the ModelForm of Django, I could not actually give the field a name, (which would have been name) and 2. Django instead fills me the name with the csrf token value and 3. actually, I don't see how the requests.post presses the submit button.

What would be what is missing here in order to succeed posting the value through the form?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django web applications, at execution time the front end and the back end are separated and communicate over http/https requests and responses. The front end displays elements to the user, collects input, etc, but then to communicate with the back end it builds a POST request from that data and sends it when the user clicks submit. The form itself is not sent, just a collection of key value pairs corresponding to the fields of the form and the user input in each of those fields. On the back end that data is handed to the form so it can validate/save/etc.

So to answer your questions:

1) I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but the important thing is that the post payload has a key that matches the name of the field in the corresponding Django form.

2) CSRF tokens are a security measure, and you'll have to manually account for this in your `requests.post` call. It may be easier to start by disabling them until you get your post working and then work on getting them working.

3) The `requests.post` doesn't actually press the submit button, you are just recreating the same http request that gets generated by the browser when a user presses the submit button. Does this make sense? This is a key point to understand.

Finally, in order to help you with a working solution we would need to see more. What does your form look like? What does your view look like?

Comment: that is good. I did not lack that much in the understanding on how the form works,. I know that via GET the data are submitted as part of the URL, visible in kev value pairs & while via POST it is constructed in the backend. My fear that this would not work is because the csrf is there precisely to prevent XSS attacks whereby, as nearly all serious forms are built using frameworks, I dont see how this requests.post can be of any real use, unless you are dealing with a simple form written in raw php or python or similar.  Definitively your input added value. The form was just 1 field.